# Rails: Show a list of lists (i.e. a has_many, belongs_to relation) in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, capybara

What is the Rails way of implementing a view for a data model that contains elements with a has_many/belongs_to relationship?

Here is the model I want to show in list form:
Driver

```
class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :cars
end
```

Here is the model that should be listed underneath each driver:

Car

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :driver
end
```

I want to show a list of drivers with their respective cars.

This raises two questions:

1 . How do I most efficiently list both in one page? What would my controller and view have to look like? If I simply do

```
    @drivers = Driver.all
```

I do not seem to get access to the cars in the view.

2 . If I only list the drivers, and load the cars upon request using AJAX, would I use a cars_controller and a drivers_controller? How would I approach writing tests for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on what you already have:

```
//controller
  @drivers = Driver.all

  //view
  @drivers.each do |d|
   puts d.messages
   # OR
   d.messages.each do |m|
    puts m.title
   end
  end
```

The same can be done inversely with `@cars = Car.all`.

Comment: Hmm... There must be something missing in my code. I am getting undefined method `cars' for #<Array:0x007f9c5d4faf00>.

Comment: You have to make sure a car object exists for a particular driver (I made a derp).  Check my edited answer.

Comment: Glad you fixed @drivers.cars ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) If you have a route you can access it directly

routes.rb

```
  resources :drivers do
    resources :cars
  end
```

to see avialable routes call `rake routes`

Then, when you initialize all drivers with `@drivers = Driver.all` you can access each driver and do `driver.cars` and access each car with `.each`

So, in the view it will look like `@drivers.each do |driver|` then you can do `driver.cars.each` .. if its empty you can build an empty one with `driver.cars.build`

for efficiency check http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-rails3/ and https://github.com/orslumen/record-cache

2) You can use the drivers controller, unless you want to use that for specific pages.

Since you can access the driver's relations from the page and you are technically in a  driver's page with different functionality then keep it in the drivers_controller.  If you feel that you are doing other stuff you can create a new controller for that.